# Postgresql sum with transpose

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

My input table has count of values for events belonging to specific categories for every year.

| events | year | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 2022 | A |
| 13 | 2022 | B |
| 3 | 2022 | C |
| 113 | 2022 | D1 |
| 1 | 2022 | D2 |
| 2 | 2022 | D3 |
| 5 | 2023 | A |
| 8 | 2023 | B |

I need to show a sum of the events for each category for each year, in the specific case I'd also need to aggregate D1+D2+D3 together).

Expected Output:

| year | events-total | category A | category B | category C | category D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 148 | 16 | 13 | 3 | 116 |
| 2023 | 13 | 5 | 8 | 0 | 0 |

The main problem of my attempts comes from the fact that there are challenges from:
1 - years that dont have events in certain categories,
2 - the years are only 2 for now, but will grow as time goes by

I tried breaking the sql with several views but cannot preview in future years the cases where some categories don't have values.

I'd like to have a sql query that handles future cases.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post the query so far you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case of a pivoting task.

In your specific case the `CASE` expressions help you to gather specific count of events to be summed up, then you can aggregate on your year_ values. You can detect the D values with the `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT year_, 
       SUM(events_)                                              AS events_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category    = 'A'  THEN events_ ELSE 0 END) AS categoryA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category    = 'B'  THEN events_ ELSE 0 END) AS categoryB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category    = 'C'  THEN events_ ELSE 0 END) AS categoryC,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category LIKE 'D%' THEN events_ ELSE 0 END) AS categoryD
FROM tab
GROUP BY year_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZqJbcaUk3ERnQeaw8Vj9L/0).

---

Using the `FILTER` operator, combined with the `COALESCE` function, would come out like this:

```
SELECT year_, 
       SUM(events_)                                               AS events_total,
       COALESCE(SUM(events_) FILTER(WHERE category    = 'A' ), 0) AS catA,
       COALESCE(SUM(events_) FILTER(WHERE category    = 'B' ), 0) AS catB,
       COALESCE(SUM(events_) FILTER(WHERE category    = 'C' ), 0) AS catC,
       COALESCE(SUM(events_) FILTER(WHERE category LIKE 'D%'), 0) AS catD
FROM tab
GROUP BY year_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZqJbcaUk3ERnQeaw8Vj9L/1).

Comment: Alternatively: `sum(events) filter (where category = ...)`

Comment: very good, both solutions work as needed, thank you very much for clear identification of type of problem, in this case, Pivoting